# What to call a positive notice for employees

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

If an employee did something wrong, he/she signs a warning notice. when the employee does something right, what do we call the act of praising the employee?
In fact, I want to show my employees that they are doing a great job, so I want to hang a paper on the wall where the good deeds are stated beside the employee name... do you have any idea what is the name of this paper?

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy don't you have the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call it an *acclamation* or a *commendation*. [The full set of synonyms is in the thesaurus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/recognition).

Answer (score 4):

A rather slangier word is **attaboy** and a somewhat cynical view of the entire process of issuing performance notifications/awards is contained in
[image]
Note the last line.

Comment: One attaboy coming up for the image. Sadly it is not signed by George H. W. Bush only by his son.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many ways. One of them is...

> A word of appreciation

This may suit to your purpose. A paper with the heading and down there the content that praises/tells about the good deeds.

Depending upon the context, such as appreciation at workplace, for support, love, gift etc. [*it may differ*](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-words-of-appreciation.html).